# Menu Code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML code**:

```
<div id="shop-slide">
    <div id="shop-content">
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <h1>You have selected services</h1>
            <input type="text" class="field" name="login" value="Return code SMS..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Return code SMS....') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Return code SMS....';}" />
            <input type="text" class="field" name="codesms" value="Nick ..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Nick ...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Nick ...';}" />
            <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="shop-toggle">
    <p>Buy</p>
    <p style="display: none;"><img class="close" src="images/close.png" alt="" />Close</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#shop-toggle').click(function() {
        $('#shop-content').slideToggle(300, function() {
            $("#shop-toggle p").toggle();
        });
    });
});
```

**CSS code**

```
#sklep {
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-right:30%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    padding: 0;
}
#sklep a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
#sklep a:hover {
    color: #616161;
}
#shop-slide {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #3b3b3b;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#shop-content {
    width: 290px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 13px;
    display: none;
}
#shop-content p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#shop-toggle {
    width: 174px;
    height: 41px;
    background: url(images/btn.png) no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #a20b1b;
    line-height: 37px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sklep-toggle:hover {
    color: #41070d;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ee4557;
}
.sklep-toggle p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.field {
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px #303030;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 9px 13px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #343434;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#ffffff), color-stop(4%, #eeeeee), to(#ffffff));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #eeeeee 1px, #ffffff 25px);
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
.submit {
    width: 120px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    padding: 8px 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #484848;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background: #6f6f6f;
    border: solid 1px #303030;
}
.submit:hover {
    background: #636363;
}
.close {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0px 3px 0px -16px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I am using this code to eject the menu, html code is linked to mysql, displays several queries.
But I have a problem, when I click button, the menu  when the button click all stand out at a time  put forward because there are a few queries.

that doesn't work :(

[Demo Webiste](http://jsfiddle.net/9X9fL/1/) 
see how it looks

please help

Comment: I really would like to help you in this, could you please explain " the menu when the button click all stand out at a time put forward because there are a few queries", I am not able to understand what is happening :(

Comment: "html code is linked to mysql" does not make sense. Do you call a script (PHP script for example) which call your database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/9X9fL/5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.shop-toggle').click(function() {
      $this = $(this);
       $this.prev().find('.shop-content').slideToggle(300,function(){
         $this.find("p").toggle();
      });
   });
});
```

Html:

```
<div  class="shop-toggle">
    <p style="display: none;">Buy</p>
    <p <img class="close" src="images/close.png" alt="" />Close</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Umm...This is as same as OP posted.

Comment: With `.shop-toggle` you get all element which have `class="shop-toggle"` not `id="shop-toggle"`. You have to use # in order to get the id

Comment: @pith I just fixed the code in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9X9fL/1/) provided by OP..

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't see you have modify the HTML

Comment: a what do you think to apply parent,children,find ?but not know how to use: D

Comment: Go to the Demo Website :) There are 2 table that information to them are loaded from the database, and it is a problem because when I click buy stand out 2 at a time..

Comment: Sry..couldn't access it..unreachable..:(

Comment: See the updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9X9fL/5/)**, also don't using duplicate `id`s.. It should be unique.. You need to fix it in your Html..

Comment: but this is not it, because the two fields are read from the database so no change in html, because every record to the database would probably have to change the html code,sorry my English is not very good ;D

Comment: This code reads the position from the database, because I see something that maybe you did not understand :)

Comment: Can you please replace your script with the one  I provided

Comment: Also, I understood the php code you provided.. In that the `<div id="shop-slide">` being inside while loop will be repeated whih will create duplicate `id`s...

Comment: this is my entire code that loads these items. http://awesomeness.hostingsiteforfree.com/indexx.txt   and http://awesomeness.hostingsiteforfree.com/indexx.txt  and this cancellation which shows it all, and here is the problem because when click to buy displays 2 tables at once

Comment: Replace `$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.shop-toggle').click(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $('.shop-content').slideToggle(300,function(){
         $this.closest("p").toggle();
      });
   });
});` in your code with `$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.shop-toggle').click(function() {
      $this = $(this);
       $this.prev().find('.shop-content').slideToggle(300,function(){
         $this.find("p").toggle();
      });
   });
});`